# Should we update the "voxels" tag information?

Tags: discussion, tags

Currently the [voxels](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/voxels) tag's description is this:

> VOlumetric piXEL (volumetric picture element). An approach to world construction that uses small, uniform volumetric elements as opposed to the larger, non-uniform polyhedra most commonly found in contemporary games.

The term "voxels" is traditionally used to describe a volume storage type, which uses a regular grid of values, "uniform volumetric elements" is just one of the many ways to represent it (this misunderstanding probably comes from the popularity of games, such as Minecraft).

The current description excludes game with isosurface-based models or terrain, such as the whole Worms series.

Comment: Do you want to write a new description for it?

Comment: @Byte56 The tag info should be changed to something like "VOlumetric piXEL (volumetric picture element). A way to store volume data as a regular grid of values."

Comment: Put your description as an answer here and I'll update it, or just modify the tag description yourself.

Comment: This tells me what a voxel is; it does *not* tell me how to *use the tag*. We are not informing users of definitions, here. We are establishing tag usage.

Comment: Voxels don't need to be rectangular and the resulting isosurface / mesh does not need to be rectangular, either. The tag seems to be very limited to minecraft-style voxels. it doesn't even fit most other voxels games like Space Engineers and Emyprion. It should be overhauled complely. And it should clearly mention when to use it and when not.